# Balanced Binary Tree Vs Balanced Binary Search Tree

Tags: algorithm, tree, binary-tree, big-o, binary-search-tree

For each of these operations would a balanced binary search tree complete the task in a faster big oh time than a balanced binary tree?

1. Finding the smallest item in the tree.

I think balanced BST would have a faster big oh time than a balanced Binary Tree since you can just keep traversing left and find the smallest item. I think it would be O(log n).

2. Creating a list of all elements in the tree that are smaller than some value v.

For 2 could someone offer me an explanation about which one would have a faster big oh time?

Comment: feel free for any queries.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**You also have to take into account best, average and worst case scenarios in time complexity performance, keeping in mind what the value of `n` represents:**

---

**1. Balanced Binary Search Tree representation**

```
           25             // Level 1
        20    36          // Level 2
      10 22  30 40        // Level 3
  .. .. .. .. .. .. .. 
.. .. .. .. .. .. .. ..   // Level n
```

---

**2. Binary Search Tree representation**

```
           10           // Level 1
          9  11         // Level 2
         7 . . 20       // Level 3
        8 . . . 15 24   
       6 . . . . . . .  // Level n
```

> Finding the smallest item in the tree.

This is a search operation.

**1)** The time complexity in here is **O(log n)**, even in worst case scenario, because the tree is balanced. The minimum value is 10.

**2)** The time complexity here in the worst case scenario is **O(n)**. The minimum value is 6. You can picture from the representation that the root's left tree (branch) behaves like a linked list. This is because the tree is unbalanced. [[1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Best,_worst_and_average_case)]

> Creating a list of all elements in the tree that are smaller than some value v.

This would be an insertion operation.

**1)** This would be **O(log n)**, because as the tree is traversed it is balanced so you don't get 2)'s scenario.

**2)** This would be **O(n)**, because in the worst case scenario your insertion will resemble insertion of a linked list.

**In conclusion:**
A Balanced Binary Search Tree guarantees **O(log n)** in all cases of search, insertion and deletion of nodes, where as a typical BST does not.

---

**Citations**

[Best, worst and average case [1]](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Best,_worst_and_average_case)

Comment: The "Asymptotic analysis" is all about the worst case my friend.

Comment: by the way, how can you classify creating a list of all the elements less than v as insertion operation.

Comment: It's about all cases my friend and check your sources, because some of your analyses are wrong. Might want to edit them.

Comment: please specify the mistake

Comment: Picture a BST and insert in this order {10,9,8,7,6,5,4,3,2,1}...that is the worst case scenario for a BST insertion. It's O(n), same as a linked list.

Comment: that is not even remotely related to my answer.

Answer (score 1):

> Creating a list of all elements in the tree that are smaller than some
>   value v.

Well, in **Big O** notation both `balanced binary search tree` and `balanced binary tree` would perform the same and time would be **O(N)**, which is linear time complexity.

For the `Balanced Binary Search tree`, we would do an [**inorder traversal**](http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/tree-traversals-inorder-preorder-and-postorder/) and keep adding all the keys to the list until we encounter the node with key `v`(inorder traversal of `BST` leads to ascending ordering of keys). Now worst case occurs when `v` is the largest key that is present in the `BST`, therefore, time complexity is **O(N)**.

For a `balanced binary tree`, its as good as traversing the entire tree and adding all the keys to the list that are less than `v`. So time complexity here also is **O(N)**.